# Proper method to access Play! cache in Scala templates?

Tags: session, scala, playframework

I'm running a Play! app using Scala templates. However, I can't find an elegant method to access the Cache in an elegant (or valid) way inside of html templates.

I've tried everything like:

```
<some html>@play.cache.Cache.get(play.session.getId() + "-account")</some html>
```

But no luck. Thanks for the proper way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the methodology buried in the old 0.9 Scala documentation. For the time being it's not super-easy but it's 3min do-able. It requires adding a parameter to the controller and template like so:

In your controller, pass session as a parameter

```
object Application extends Controller {

    import views.Application._

    def index = {
        html.index(session)
    }
}
```

At the top of your template, define the implicit variable:

```
@(implicit session:play.mvc.Scope.Session)
```

Inside the template html, access it like so:

```
@(play.cache.Cache.get(session.getId() + "-account"))
```